# How to disclose school vulnerability as student

Tags: disclosure

Let’s just say I’m in high school. If I were to of found a way to access all of the schools finals, mid terms, home work assignments, school ids (tied to names), passwords, grades of finals for every student in last 5 years, and stuff on that line. How much trouble would I be in? Also if I were to tell IT to help them, would I get in trouble?

Comment: I would recommend at the very least trying to see if you can find a teacher (preferably with some technical knowledge) who will help you raise this with the administration. I've heard plenty of stories of schools freaking out on students trying to do the right thing, so having an adult sponsor would be helpful. Also, how much information did you access? The less you viewed, the better, liability-wise.

Comment: I would recommend against talking to even a supportive teacher. Invariably that teacher will be asked by higher-ups where the information came from and you cannot expect the teacher to protect you at their expense. Tell no one, not even your friends, and stay well clear of the vulnerability. All it takes is one senior administrator who lacks technical knowlege to start the attack against the evil hacker child who can't defend themselves. In their mind, there was no problem until you came along.